# MongoDB in Docker - backup database on container shutdown

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup docker-compose with Node and MongoDB. In combination with the official Mongo container I'm using a dedicated container ([mongodb-backup](https://github.com/tutumcloud/mongodb-backup)) for continuous backups of the database and an initial restore at startup.

My problem is how to trigger a backup in case of a graceful shutdown by `docker-compose stop`.
Therefore it's necessary to shut down the Node container at first to guarantee no process is writing to the database. Then backup the database and finally shutdown the mongodb and mongodb-backup conatainers.

This [repository](https://github.com/twittwer/mongodb-backup/tree/docker-compose) contains my docker-compose setup of mongodb and mongodb-backup.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear to me. Do you mean, how can you restore your data from the backup after the mongo container screwed up?

Comment: No, the restore is handled by the mongodb-backup container. I want to backup (dump) the database before the mongodb container is shut down.

Comment: I suppose you do the backups in order to not lose data for the case that the mongodb container screws up. So the only way to do it, is to schedule a daily or hourly backup. How can you know when your mongodb container shuts down next time? Only for a planned maintenance. Is this your case?

Comment: The scheduled backup is already implemented. My use case now is for example the maintenance.
So I want to automatically save the latest data in case of a planned `docker-compose stop`.

Comment: OK, now it is clear for me what you wanna do. May be you wanna update your question above in order that you get answers from the community asap.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small maintenance script for this case. Instead of doing a raw `docker-compose stop`, you could just run this script instead. Let's call it maintenance.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
docker-compose stop app
docker-compose stop mongo-backup # ensure only one is active
docker-compose run --rm -e INIT_BACKUP=1 # do the backup manually
docker-compose stop mongo # stop the database
```

Comment: Can the downvoters at least have the courtesy to leave a comment? I am happy to adjust my answer if there is a problem.